# Updatedb unrecognized option '--localpaths='

Tags: command-line, updatedb

I am attempting to update a single directory I created. I'm using `updatedb` so it will be found by  the `locate` command.

Command used:
`updatedb --localpaths='/frodo/lib/modules/3.12.3-031203-generic/kernel'`

Output:
`updatedb: unrecognized option '--localpaths=/frodo/lib/modules/3.12.3-031203-generic/kernel'`

Same result with:

```
updatedb --localpaths=  
updatedb: unrecognized option '--localpaths='
```

From `man updatedb`:

> ```
>    --localpaths='path1 path2...'
>           Non-network directories to put in the database.  Default is /.
> ```

**Why does it give this error when `--localpaths` is clearly stated as an option?**

---

Sytem info:

> ```
> updatedb --version
> updatedb (mlocate) 0.26
> Copyright (C) 2007 Red Hat, Inc. All rights reserved.
> This software is distributed under the GPL v.2.
>
> This program is provided with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> lsb_release -a
> LSB Version:  core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:
> core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-
> noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 13.10
> Release:  13.10
> Codename: saucy
>
> uname -r
> 3.12.3-031203-generic
> ```

---

Edit: I have had success with `updatedb -U /frodo/lib/modules/3.12.3-031203-generic/kernel`, but I would still like to know why the `--localpaths` from the manual is not recognized.

This alternative option is not in the manual, but found with `updatedb -h`.

> ```
>    -U, --database-root PATH       the subtree to store in database 
> (default "/")
> ```

Comment: I think it would be better if you share your OS name and updatedb version. (  `updatedb --version` )

Comment: This user has the same version of `updatedb`, yet the selected answer seems to have worked: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151700/how-to-add-specific-directories-to-updateb-locate-search-path

Comment: If there's some discrepancy with the same application version between distributions, I'd suggest filing a bug by the distribution that exhibits the odd behaviour so the package maintainer is aware of the issue, Ubuntu in this case. Might be a mistake in packaging man pages with the wrong binaries. Just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two popular implementations of updatedb. One of them is [from GNU findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-updatedb.html#Invoking-updatedb). Another is [mlocate](https://fedorahosted.org/mlocate/). They support different command line options and configuration files, especially for the `updatedb` program.

It appears that the `updatedb` command on your system is the one from mlocate but the man page is the one from findutils. Normally, Ubuntu has a system (inherited from Debian) called [alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) which ensures that when there are multiple implementations of a program, the choice of program and the choice of man page are consistent. However, in this case, the `updatedb` man page isn't recorded in the list of alternatives, only the `locate` executable, the `locate` man page and the `updatedb` executable are. This is because the `updatedb` man pages are in a different section: findutils puts it in section 1 but mlocate puts it in section 8. Thus `man 1 updatedb` shows the `updatedb(1)` man page, because it's the only `updatedb` man page in section 1. And `man updatedb` shows the man page in section 1 because that's the first section with a match. Arguably, that's a packaging bug in mlocate: the findutils and mlocate package maintainers should agree to put the man pages for `updatedb` in the same section, and mlocate should declare an alternative for its man page; since mlocate puts `updatedb` in `/usr/bin`, its man page should be in section 1. As things stand, you can see the man page for the mlocate `updatedb` with `man 8 updatedb`.

The mlocate implementation of `updatedb` doesn't have an option that's exactly equivalent to findutils's `--localpaths`. You can create a separate database and specify what subtree it contains with the `--database-root` option, or run `updatedb --database-root / --database-root /frodo/lib/modules/3.12.3-031203-generic/kernel`.

Comment: Well done! It is indeed using the `mlocate` version  whose documentation is at `updatedb(8)`.

Comment: If you want to change from an implementation to another one, you must to execute (in Debian and derivatives) `update-alternatives --config locate`, and select the desired alternative to `locate`.

Comment: @AndrésMorales You can do that, but you don't have to. You can call e.g. `mlocate` explicitly if you want. This lets you choose your locate implementation even if you don't have root access which is required to run `update-alternatives`.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, it's correct, but if your default alternative is `mlocate` you must to type `locate.findutils` to use the another one.